# On converting Html to Pdf body top styling is having extra padding and margin

Tags: html, css

[image]

So on converting extra top space is appering from left and top on converting to pdf

Comment: those margins you see are from / for your printer. :)

Comment: AJAX, did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The margin is the default margin for printing pages. To remove this, on the print window open *more setting*s and select the margin > none.

[image]